# Cannot access variable from named imports in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, babeljs

I have a library for vue components.

components/index.js

```
import Graphs from './graphs/index.js'
import Tabs from './Tab'
export default { Graphs, Tab }
```

then on index.js

```
import lib from 'components/index.js'
export default lib
```

I install my lib on my vue app then

On my vue app I have the following:

```
import {Graphs} from lib
console.log(Graphs) >> undefined
```

However, using the default import and accessing the variable it works:

```
import lib from lib
console.log(lib.Graphs) >> Object { props: {…}, computed: {…}, data: data(), methods: {…}, render: render(), staticRenderFns: [], _scopeId: "data-v-41c28542", beforeCreate: (1) […] }
```

I have a feeling this has to do with either webpack or a babel module, or maybe something I'm missing but cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like using an imported object does not allow for named imports later.

So even though lib is an object with keys for Graphs it does not work after importing it like that.

So what I had to do was export those again as named exports.

so index.js became:

```
import lib from './components/index'
export let Graphs = lib.Graphs
export default lib
```

Answer (score 0):

in your index file you  will get result

```
// import lib from "components/index.js";
//  given result lib.Graphs, lib.Tabs
//  then you exporting object like { lib: { Graphs: '....', Tabs: '...' } }
export default { lib };
```

because have this result. 
in this situation index.js action is unnecessary

Comment: It isn't unnecessary, as I will add code from more files in the future. 

As I rewrote the code for the SO question I made the mistake of adding extra braces to the export default. I've edited that. Thanks.